# Obtener array dentro de una tabla

Tags: php, array, base-de-datos

Tengo una base de datos en las que guardo arrays, `{"top":"checked","mid":"checked","adc":"checked","supp":"checked","jg":"checked"}`
Pero no me deja leerlo en php, he intentando de todo, **json_decode/encode()**, **array()**, etc. En la base de datos lo guardo así:`{"top":"checked","mid":"checked","adc":"checked","supp":"checked","jg":"checked"}` 
Pero al obtener los rows, php lo reconoce como un *string*

Comment: A mi me funciona bien con `json_decode`

Comment: Que es lo que haces, un echo, implode o print_r? Yo no puedo hacer ni foreach ni while.. Saludos @alanfcm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi me funciona el siguiente codigo con `json_decode`:

```
<?php

$str = '{"top":"checked","mid":"checked","adc":"checked","supp":"checked","jg":"checked"}';

$arr = json_decode($str);

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . ": " . $val . "<br>";
}

?>
```